# How to make static IP address dynamic in /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, ip, static-ip

I need to set the  IP address of a ubuntu device() to be read from an EEPROM. The user has he option to change the IP address as well.

I  know the commands to read and write to the EEPROM. But how do I edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` file so that it automatically fetches the IP address from the EEPROM on network start/restart?

Btw..I am aware of the methods to configure static IP address the normal way. But in that method, I could only hardcode the IP address in the interfaces file. Is there any way I can make this a variable, which I can populate from EEPROM and use in the interfaces file?

Also, I know that I can do the whole thing using a shell script by calling the EEPROM command and ifconfig. But I would like to do this using the standard init scripts. Also I need DHCP configuration to happen in the standard way.

Comment: Could you post the output of the command you're using that reads the IP address from the EEPROM?  (No NVRAM?)

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html

Comment: @Fabby I am planning to use something like this :
`dd if=sys/bus/i2c/drivers/at24/0-0050/eeprom count=1 bs=1 skip=48`

But I can warp this in a script and return whatever I want. I am more concerned about how this string can be used in the configuration file.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question so that all important information is in there?  (the above comment!) Then add the `of=/tmp/eeprom.txt` parameters to ´dd´ and post the contents of the file `eeprom.txt` to http://paste.ubuntu.com and provide a link back (also in your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/965744/storing-and-retrieving-a-static-ip-address-in-a-non-standard-location-in-debian/965755#965755) from superuser site. The [debian manual](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Bringing_up_an_interface_without_an_IP_address) says that it is possible to configure an interface without an IP address like this:

```
   iface eth0 inet manual
      pre-up /path/to/script/which_changes_your_ip.sh
      post-down /path/to/script/which_removes_your_ip.sh
```

I am not sure how I can give credit to the person who gave me the solution. So I will just accept my answer itself.